# Is there any way to make position:sticky work inside iframe based on the parent document scroll?

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, css-animations, css-position

I am having a usecase where the `<footer>` inside the `<iframe>` should be sticky at bottom (`<iframe>` doesn't have a scrollbar) based on the parent document scroll.

**Note:**
`position: sticky` works as expected inside `<iframe>` only when it has a scroll.

Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

Their is not a way to do this with css of standard browser APIs. You might however find it useful to look at a library called
[iframe-resizer](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer) which provides an API to tell the iframe the [scroll position of the parent page](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer/blob/master/docs/iframed_page/methods.md#getpageinfocallback--false).

You would then need to write a little bit of JS to take this stream of position data and use it to position your div.

Comment: Thanks @DavidBradshaw. I am able to make the `footer` sticky inside iframe, but the footer is flickering everytime I scroll, I believe this is happening because of changing the position of the element on scroll. I have added `requestAnimationFrame` and used transform to change the position of element. Any thoughts?

Comment: I would use the performance monitor in Chrome to see what is slowing things down then. It might be something else on the page. 

The only other suggestion that I have is to put a flag on the calls to requestAnimatrionFrame. You can get problems if something else slows down the render and you miss a frame that you ended up calling it a bunch of times for the same frame.